# How can I suppress \\ in my output from Perl's JSON module?

Tags: perl, json, escaping

Following code always print paths with double slashes:

```
use JSON;
use File::Spec;

my $installdir   = $ENV{"ProgramFiles"};
my $xptrlc = File::Spec->catfile($installdir,"bin","sample");

my $jobhash;
my $return_packet;
$jobhash->{'PATH'} = $xptrlc;
$return_packet->{'JOB'} = $jobhash;

my $js = new JSON;
my $str = $js->objToJson($return_packet);

print STDERR "===> $str \n";
```

OUTPUT of this script is

```
===> {"JOB":{"PATH":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\bin\\sample"}}
```

Any solution to remove those double `\\` slashes?

Comment: If you removed them it wouldn't be correct JSON any more

Comment: Do you have an error when tring to parse this output with Javascript?

Comment: I am not java expert, But What should happen when I parse this JSON on GUI side and display it, should it show \\ or single slash \

Comment: `'JavaScript' ne 'Java'`

Comment: It should show a single slash. But note that this has nothing to do with Java. It is the JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: The "OUTPUT" of the script is what I like to call, "correct".  If you want to output incorrect data, I recommend `perl -e 'print chr rand 255 for 1..100'`.  Much shorter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24181/greg) mentioned, the '`\`' character is represented as '`\\`' in JSON.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to use "thaw" the JSON somewhere, like in another Perl program or in JavaScript, you will still get back exactly what you put in.

Are you trying to do something else with your JSON?

Answer (score 3):

Windows is perfectly fine with using `'/'` in paths if that bothers you so much:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use JSON;
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);

my $installdir = $ENV{ProgramFiles};
my $xptrlc = catfile $installdir,qw(bin sample);
$xptrlc =~ s'\\'/'g;

my $packet = { JOB => { PATH => $xptrlc } };

my $js = JSON->new;
my $str = $js->encode($packet);

warn "===> $str \n";
```

Output:

```
===> {"JOB":{"PATH":"C:/Program Files/bin/sample"}}
```

On the other hand, the encoded value will be correctly decoded:

```
use JSON;
warn JSON->new->decode(scalar <DATA>)->{JOB}->{PATH}, "\n";

__DATA__
{"JOB":{"PATH":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\bin\\sample"}}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> ht
C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\sample
```

Comment: Amen.  I wish more people knew this trick.  I've seen so much "portable" code jump through needless hoops trying to handle windows paths.

Comment: Hoops are still required.  `/C:/Program Files/bin/sample` is not valid, after all.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  That's a perfectly valid windows path AFAICT.  It lives underneath a directory named "C:" on the current drive.  Obviously the filesystem layouts are different, but an app with a given file structure under the cwd can always use the same paths between systems.